# Error when calculating morphological tessellation cells with momepy library

Tags: geopandas, osmnx, pysal

"Momepy is a library for quantitative analysis of urban form - urban morphometrics. It is part of PySAL (Python Spatial Analysis Library) and is built on top of GeoPandas, other PySAL modules and networkX." [momepy documentation](http://docs.momepy.org/en/stable/)

Using code (relevant portion below) from Fleischmann, Martin, Alessandra Feliciotti, and William Kerr. “Evolution of Urban Patterns: Urban Morphology as an Open Reproducible Data Science.” Geographical Analysis, July 15, 2021, gean.12302. https://doi.org/10.1111/gean.12302.

I am using OSM data to examine the morphometric character of a four small cities in central Illinois, USA. For a reason I cannot understand, I am encountering problems with the calculation of morphological tessellation cells in **only one** of the cities. I have included a link to an image of the tessellation cells below (I was not allowed to embed a photo).

Thank you for any assistance!

```
%%capture --no-stdout

for i, coords in cases.origin.iteritems():
    s = time()
    """
    donwload and process elements of urban form
    """
    # download buildings from OSM
    point = tuple(map(float, coords[1:-1].split(', ')))[::-1]
    buildings = osmnx.geometries.geometries_from_point(point, dist=1000, tags={'building':True})
    buildings = osmnx.projection.project_gdf(buildings)
    buildings = buildings[buildings.geom_type.isin(['Polygon', 'MultiPolygon'])]
    buildings = buildings.reset_index(drop=True).explode().reset_index(drop=True)
    buildings = buildings[["geometry"]]

    # download streets from OSM
    streets_graph = osmnx.graph_from_point(point, 1250, network_type='drive')
    streets_graph = osmnx.get_undirected(streets_graph)
    streets_graph = osmnx.projection.project_graph(streets_graph)
    streets = osmnx.graph_to_gdfs(streets_graph, nodes=False, edges=True,
                                            node_geometry=False, fill_edge_geometry=True)
    streets = streets[["geometry"]]

    # check CRS
    assert buildings.crs.equals(streets.crs)

    # generate tessellation
    buildings['uID'] = range(len(buildings))
    tessellation = mm.Tessellation(buildings, "uID", limit=box(*buildings.total_bounds), verbose=False).tessellation

    """
    measure morphometric characters
    """
    # cell area
    tessellation['cell_area'] = tessellation.area

    # building area
    buildings['blg_area'] = buildings.area

    # coverage area ratio
    tessellation["car"] = mm.AreaRatio(tessellation, buildings, "cell_area", buildings.area, "uID").series

    # segment length
    streets["length"] = streets.length

    # segment linearity
    streets["linearity"] = mm.Linearity(streets, verbose=False).series

    # street profile
    profile = mm.StreetProfile(streets, buildings, distance=3)
    streets["width"] = profile.w
    streets["width_deviation"] = profile.wd
    streets["openness"] = profile.o

    # perimeter wall
    buildings["wall"] = mm.PerimeterWall(buildings, verbose=False).series

    # generate binary contiguity-based W objects of first order and inclusive order 3
    W1 = libpysal.weights.Queen.from_dataframe(tessellation, ids="uID")
    W3 = mm.sw_high(k=3, weights=W1)

    # building adjacency
    buildings["adjacency"] = mm.BuildingAdjacency(buildings, W3, "uID", verbose=False).series

    # interbuilding distance
    buildings['neighbour_distance'] = mm.NeighborDistance(buildings, W1, 'uID', verbose=False).series

    # generate networkx.MultiGraph object
    G = mm.gdf_to_nx(streets)

    # meshedness
    G = mm.meshedness(G, verbose=False)

    # convert networkx.MultiGraph to geopandas.GeoDataFrames
    nodes, edges = mm.nx_to_gdf(G)

    """
    link all characters to tessellation cells
    """
    # merge street network edges based on proximity
    edges["nID"] = range(len(edges))
    buildings["nID"] = mm.get_network_id(buildings, edges, "nID", 500, verbose=False)
    buildings = buildings.merge(edges.drop(columns="geometry"), on="nID", how="left")

    # merge nodes based on edge ID and proximity
    buildings["nodeID"] = mm.get_node_id(buildings, nodes, edges, "nodeID", "nID", verbose=False)
    buildings = buildings.merge(nodes.drop(columns="geometry"), on="nodeID", how="left")

    # merge buildings based on a shared attribute
    tessellation = tessellation.merge(buildings.drop(columns="geometry"), on="uID", how="left")

    """
    save all to GeoPackage
    """
    tessellation.to_file(f"~/work/{cases.loc[i, 'case']}.gpkg", layer="tessellation", driver="GPKG")
    buildings.to_file(f"~/work/{cases.loc[i, 'case']}.gpkg", layer="buildings", driver="GPKG")
    edges.to_file(f"~/work/{cases.loc[i, 'case']}.gpkg", layer="edges", driver="GPKG")
    nodes.to_file(f"~/work/{cases.loc[i, 'case']}.gpkg", layer="nodes", driver="GPKG")

    print(f"{cases.loc[i, 'case']} done in {time() - s} seconds.")
```

[Notice the dense bundles of tessellation cells - they do not correspond correctly to the underlying buildings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odoBS.png)

Comment: This is caused by significantly overlapping or duplicated building footprint polygons. If you can share `x, y` coordinates of the Peoria case study, I can draft a workaround.

Comment: Dr. Fleischmann, I solved my problem in the short term by selecting an alternate x,y for the Peoria. In the long term, however, I will want to deal with such problems directly. Thank you very much for your reply and offer!